# Problema con wait, simular carga | Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Quiero simular una pantalla de carga con numeros pero no me funciona, con numeros.

```
`int i = 100;
 int n = 0;
 Random r = new Random();
 int random = r.nextInt(1);
 TextView percent;
 int[] opcion_0 = {1, 20, 40, 60, 89, 100};
 int[] opcion_1 = {1, 30, 60, 90, 99, 100};`
```

Esas son mis variables, con el random elijo una de esas 2 opciones. Ya cuando se elige lo agarro con un switch y lo va mostrando en pantalla con el textview (percent) pero siempre se queda en 1. Osea en el primer valor.

```
`public void cargando() {
        switch (random) {
            case 0:
                try {
                    for (int k = 0; k <= 5; k++) {
                        String temp = String.valueOf(opcion_0[n]);
                        percent.setText(temp);
                        n++;
                        wait(i);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                try {
                    for (int k = 0; k <= 5; k++) {
                        String temp = String.valueOf(opcion_1[n]);
                        percent.setText(temp);
                        n++;
                        wait(i);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                break;
         }
}`
```

El problema segun yo es en el wait, pero no estoy seguro, tambien intente con Thread.sleep(i) pero cuando abre la activity ya esta en 100 osea en el ultimo valor.

Answer (score 0):

Para tener algo interactivo como una barra de progreso debes actualizar su valor en un hilo diferente al principal. El proyecto debe tener habilitado java 8.

```
public void cargando() {
  // esto te permite ejecutar hilos secundarios y manipular la UI como si fuera
  // el hilo principal
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  switch (random) {
      case 0:
         // con el métod submit() se envía la tarea que se hará en el nuevo hilo
         // hará una pausa de un segundo ( al hilo secundario ) y actualizará 
         // el valor del elemento de la UI
         executor.submit(()->{

             for (int k = 0; k <= 5; k++) {
                 String temp = String.valueOf(opcion_0[n]);
                 percent.setText(temp);
                 n++;

                 try {
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
      break;

  }
}
```